# Removing a portion of a string that has forward slashes in it

Tags: string, parsing, sed, tr

I'm stumped with how to remove a portion of a string that has forward slashes and question marks in it.

Example: `/diag/PeerManager/list?deviceid=RXMWANT8WFYJNF7K6DXXXJLJVN`

and I need the output to be `RXMWANT8WFYJNF7K6DXXXJLJVN`

I've tried `tr` and `sed` but `tr` removes some of the characters I need in the output. `sed` is giving me trouble because of the forward slashes.

What's a quick method to remove the `/diag/PeerManager/list?deviceid=` portion of my string?
thanks!

Comment: It would help if you could be more precise about what you want to do. Remove everything before the first `=`? Remove precisely the prefix `/diag/PeerManager/list?deviceid=` if that happens to be how your string begins? Parse the string as if it comes from a URL, identify name/value pairs in the query part, and extract the value of `deviceid`? Something else entirely?

Comment: Hi, thank you and sorry for lack of detail. Yes, I'd like to remove exactly the part of the line '/diag/PeerManager/list?deviceid=' OR removing everything before the = sign would also give me what I'm looking for as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
sed 's/.*deviceid=\([^&]*\).*/\1/'
```

Example:

```
$ echo '/diag/PeerManager/list?deviceid=RXMWANT8WFYJNF7K6DXXXJLJVN' | sed 's/.*deviceid=\([^&]*\).*/\1/'
RXMWANT8WFYJNF7K6DXXXJLJVN
```

This is not the most robust solution, but if you have a fixed set of input that will never change, it's probably good enough.

Comment: Thank you cdhowie! I need to bone up on my sed chops. Very appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

> echo "/diag/PeerManager/list?deviceid=RXMWANT8WFYJNF7K6DXXXJLJVN" | sed -n 's:/[a-zA-Z]*/[a-zA-Z]*/[a-zA-Z]*?[a-zA-Z]*=::p'

This should do the trick. I chose the colon as the delimiter as it will not cause any issues with the forward slash. This makes a lot of assumptions about the type of input it will be receiving, specifically that it will only contain three backslashes with lower and uppercase letters between them, a series of letters ending in a question mark, another series of letters ending in an equals sign. This then removes those items and prints the remaining characters (your device id).

Answer (score 0):

One way using `awk`, if there is only a single occurrence of an `=`  on each line:

```
awk -F= '{ print $2 }' file.txt
```

Results:

```
RXMWANT8WFYJNF7K6DXXXJLJVN
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Use Equals Sign as Field Delimiter

If you know that your GET [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) will always have only one parameter (in this case, *deviceid*) then you can just use the equals sign as a field delimiter with the standard *cut* utility. For example:

```
$ echo '/diag/PeerManager/list?deviceid=RXMWANT8WFYJNF7K6DXXXJLJVN' |
    cut -d= -f2-
RXMWANT8WFYJNF7K6DXXXJLJVN
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$ echo /diag/PeerManager/list?deviceid=RXMWANT8WFYJNF7K6DXXXJLJVN | sed 's/^.*=//'
RXMWANT8WFYJNF7K6DXXXJLJVN
```